What is the meaning of the phrase "Il paraît" ?
What is the meaning of the phrase " Il paraît. " used by itself like in the dialogue below (it's a fragment of the interview with the creator of the dechetterie)?

Alors, c’est une première déchetterie ?
Il paraît.
Mondiale?
Il paraît.


You can literally translate it. Paraître.

Are you trying to translate it word-for-word? Because of English grammar, this doesn't quite work; you need to add a word or two—for example: so it seems or it appears to be.

Usually, "Il paraît!" means "I heard that!", but in this context, it's rather "So it seems!".

In English, we'd say apparently here.

"Il paraît." is usually used to mean "So they say.".

You will find it in French in various forms: "il paraît", "paraît-il", or "à ce qu'il paraît" or "apparement". It means the same as "apparently" or "it seems".
